# Where on my pc does iTunes store the backup?

Tags: iphone, backup

I backup my phone to iTunes but need to back up my pc.  I can do pictures as I can just copy those from the phone but what about the contacts, texts etc that are backed up to iTunes? Where is that stored?

Comment: Are you asking about the location on a Windows computer?

Answer (score 12):

From [Locate backups of your iPhone, iPad, and iPod touch](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht204215):

> iTunes places the backup files in the following places:
>
> - **Mac:** `~/Library/Application Support/MobileSync/Backup/`
> - **Windows XP:** `\Documents and Settings\(username)\Application Data\Apple Computer\MobileSync\Backup\`
>
>   **Note:** To quickly access the Application Data folder, click **Start**, and choose **Run**. Type **%appdata%** and click **OK**.
> - **Windows Vista, 7, 8, 10:** `\Users\(username)\AppData\Roaming\Apple Computer\MobileSync\Backup\`
>
>   **Note:** To quickly access the AppData folder, click **Start**. In the search bar, type **%appdata%** and press the <kbd>**↩ Return**</kbd> key.

##### 20230805: "new" folder

Windows 10: `\Users\(username)\Apple\MobileSync\Backup\`

Apple might have made this the new default since a while, I can also find this folder listed at [iTunes Backup Location: Where Does iTunes Store Backups?](https://mobiletrans.wondershare.com/itunes/itunes-backup-location.html). In a new installation of iTunes on a computer that has never stored a backup before, it took this "new" folder.

Comment: I gather than you are not supposed to say thank you particularly on here but thank you so much.  I can now replace my hard drive after the backup of the backup!  :)

Comment: @madfish If the answer helped you achieve what is necessary, vote it up and tick it as being correct.

Comment: Just a note that on my Mac, these files are split apart and named in a way that they're not human-readable.

Comment: What about windows 10

Answer (score 0):

For Windows 7 & 8 (from my knowledge):

- Start iTunes and attach the iPhone.
- Click on your phone icon and then select the **Info** tab on the top menu.
- Note the drop down menu SYNC CONTACTS WITH.
- Choose Windows Contacts.
- Make sure everything else is unchecked.
- Then go ahead sync your phone.
- This creates and or updates a Contacts Folder in your Windows User's folder called Contacts.
- The info in here looks similar to a file but the columns show contact info.
- Select an entry and OPEN IT (double click or right click and choose open.) - An edit window opens. When you sync the Windows Contact folder and your iPhone you will be able to get a pretty cool reconciliation feature for the differences between the two lists.
- This works well and I know I have my contacts on my computer and backed up with all my other stuff.